# Web deploy to IIS without Visual Studio

Tags: iis, microsoft-web-deploy

I have a IIS v7.5 as my web server. This web server hosts not only ASP.NET web application, but also for PHP web apps for my company apps. What I want is to support deployment using web deploy without Visual Studio (for supporting non ASP.NET developer). Previously, we used windows share (SMB) to support deployment for non ASP.NET developer. But this option caused problem when our server attacked by virus when one of our developer deploy their web apps via windows share. 
I know there's reference from [Deploy to an Azure WebRole without Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336929/deploy-to-an-azure-webrole-without-visual-studio) but this is not deployment to azure server, but for my company web server (IIS).

Is there any web deploy client other than Visual Studio?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I have exactly the same requirement at the moment.

Comment: Still no ideal solution. There is possibility to use command line version but never try it.

Answer (score 1):

Web Deploy (MSDeploy) is actually a completely standalone product. Visual Studio's deploy tooling is (or at least was) generally referred to as the "Web Publishing Pipeline" and consists of MS**Build** targets/tasks that wrap MSDeploy (among other things)

You can call MSDeploy.exe (`%programfiles%\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe`) directly to generate packages and deploy to remote IIS servers. The tool is Windows only, obviously.

Comment: Where can I find a tutorial / example?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/introduction-to-web-deploy (+ links at bottom)  https://blog.richardszalay.com/2012/12/10/deployment-pipeline-part-1/